# VB.NET Dynamic creation of Details View with a web panel

Tags: vb.net

Every time i enter set of values like Group Name,Group Abbreviation,URL in the text boxes  and click the save button automatically its saves in the database and for each set of values a new details view has to be generated dynamically with a web panel and the header of the web panel should have the value of Group Name.
Example:

```
 Group1
```

Name                     Group1

Abbreviation              G1

URL                       http://stackoverflow.com

```
  Group2
```

Name                      Group2

Abbreviation              G2

URL                       http://stackoverflow.com

A new details view with web panel like the above has to be generated every time the save button is clicked.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes each group is a single database record.

1. Use a datasource which pulls all of the IDs for the groups that should be displayed on the page.
2. Create a repeater control and set its datasource to the datasource created in step 1
3. Add a hidden input field to the content template for the repeater control.  Bind it's value to the group's id.
4. Add a details view control to the repeater control template.
5. Add a datasource to the repeater control template that returns a group record filtered on the hidden input control.

When you submit a new group, make sure to rebind the data on the repeater control created in step 2.

Alternatively, it would be much easier to just use a listview if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.I have tried the procedure but i was not able to solve it.Can you please give the code for above explaination.